# How to sum based on variable level using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I have a dataset containing some sports performance data. Below is a small example.

```
Player.Name Period.Name Average.Distance Total.HIR V6.Distance   Date
Player 1    Quarter 1           2240.744    588.31       84.42   2/3/18
Player 2    Quarter 1           3008.554    833.94       10.50   2/3/18
Player 3    Quarter 1           2907.660    1020.78      58.52   2/3/18
Player 1    Quarter 2           2747.222    903.37       82.41   2/3/18
Player 2    Quarter 2           2225.836    679.79       31.32   2/3/18
Player 3    Quarter 2           3445.327    1034.16      108.20  2/3/18
```

I'm trying to use dplyr to sum `Quarter 1` and `Quarter 2` together for each of `Average.Distance`, `Total.HIR` and `V6.Distance`. I want to group this by `Player.Name` and `Date`, noting I have many dates in my dataset (`matchdb2018`). This is the code I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)
summary <- matchdb2018 %>%
  group_by(Player.Name, Date) %>%
```

I'm uncertain how to continue with the next line(s) of code and how to sum based on the level of a variable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall do you the work and you probably want to keep as a data frame rather than tibble object.

```
library(dplyr)
summary <- matchdb2018 %>%
  group_by(Player.Name, Date) %>%
  summarise(tot_dist=sum(Average.Distance),tot_hir=sum(Total.HIR),tot_v6=sum(V6.Distance))%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarise_at`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Player.Name) %>% 
  summarize_at(c("Average.Distance", "Total.HIR", "V6.Distance"), sum)
```

Or you can unselect the `Period.Name` (because it isn't numeric) first and use `summarize_all` ... saves some typing.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Player.Name) %>% 
  select(-Period.Name) %>%
  summarize_all(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think in your case, summarise() in dplyr will be your best option. You can do something like below.

```
library(dplyr)
summary <- matchdb2018 %>%
group_by(Player.Name, Date) %>%
summarise(col1=sum(Average.Distance),col2=sum(Total.HIR),col3=sum(V6.Distance))
```

This code will let you see the sum of Average.Distance, Total.HIR and V6.Distance by player-name and the date.